# About span and subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

I run into the theorem that states
"The span of any subset S of a vector space V is a subspace of V"
in Friedberg Linear Algebra(p30).
I know a lot are written about this theorem but I want to take a closer look at another part of this theorem, which, I at least, haven't seen in any websites thus far.
To prove that the span of any subset S is a vector space we need a couple of things:

1. span(S) is closed under addition and multiplication
2. Zero vector is in span(S)
3. span(S) ⊂ V
   I see a lot of proofs on the net that prove this theorem by showing the first two conditions.

Here is the definition of a subspace according to Freidberg(p16):
A subset W of a vector space V over a field F is called a subspace of V if W is a vector space over F with the operations of addition and scalar multiplication defined on V.

It states W must be a subset of V. (at least this is what I got). Why do the proofs on the net don't consider to prove "span(S) ⊂ V" ? Is it so obvious to see? Or... Where am I missing. It's been two days and it's really buzzing me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is obvious. The elements of the span of $S$ are linear combinations of elements in $S$. By definition, a vector space is closed under its operations of addition and scalar multiplication, so linear combinations will again be elements of $V$.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious. Since $S\subset V$,  vector operations on $S$ (which is what you do when you take the span: you take linear combinations) will stay in $V$.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that by definition, the vector space $V$ that you're working in is closed under addition and scalar multiplication, i.e. any linear combination of vectors in $V$ remains in $V$. Restricting your vectors to a subset $S\subseteq V$ leaves that property in place so to speak, so any element in the span is certainly in the underlying vector space. That is to say any linear combination of vectors in $S$ can also be viewed as a linear combination of vector in $V$ because $S \subseteq V$.

Comment: I see your point and got it. Thank you for that. Need one confirmation though. It can also be concluded that "S ⊂ span(S)" is true, right?

Comment: @H.Can Yes, by definition, $\text{span}(S)$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ that **contains** $S$, so $S\subseteq \text{span}(S)$.